# Upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 LTS 32 bit not booting

Tags: boot, 14.04

When Ubuntu 14.04 LTS tries to boot I get several lines like this:

Bad I/O access at port x20000 (out1(val, port)

The port numbers go from x2000 through x2024 at that last message the boot stalls and after a few minutes the CRT screens go black.

I tried booting with Advanced Options. There are 6 choices:

```
3.13.0.34 generic
3.13.0.34 with support

3.11.0.26 generic
3.11.0.26 with support

3.08.0-35 generic  # This one boots into 14.04 LTS
3.08.0-35 with support.
```

If I go into `3.13.0.34 with support`, I can pick to resume booting and then the boot works but the screen size is wrong.

What is wrong with the default `3.13.0.34-generic` kernel? How can I fix?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the video driver that the Ubuntu install picked.

The ports made me think it was related to PCI. PCI is the bus where the video card is. I changed the video driver and that fixed the issue.

In order to get to it I booted in recovery then picked continue to boot from the top recovery option. I could see only one of my dual monitors came up so that was another clue. From this boot I was able to go into settings and software updates to change the video driver.